# execl is suceeding - however exit(1) is being called

Tags: c, error-handling, exec

I'm trying to better understand exec() - so I have the following script in `testing.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if(argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error:: Expecting an Argument!\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid==0) {
    execlp("./testing","testing",NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "I want to get to here...\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  wait(NULL);
  printf("Parent and child done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

The block below is the output after I execute with `./testing one`:

```
Error:: Expecting an Argument!
Parent and child done
```

In reading how `exec()` works, I was expecting to be able to `fprintf` after my `execlp` call since it should be returning -1, I'm wondering if I need to be setting an errno or something or being more explicity about throwing something so that `execlp` recoginize the error?

Comment: `man 3 exec`: *RETURN VALUE
       The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.  The return value is -1, and errno is set to  in‐
       dicate the error.*

Comment: What makes you think that the `execlp` call failed?

Comment: regarding: `Error:: Expecting an Argument!`  This message is because you did NOT supply a command line parameter, which the code is expecting

Comment: the posted code does not compile! It is missing the following  `#include` statements:     #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

Comment: when a command line parameter is included, then the output is: `I want to get to here...
Parent and child done`

Comment: OT: The `fork()` function has three kinds of returned values:  `<0` means an error occurred   `==0` means in the child process   `>0` means in the parent process.  The code should be checking for all three(3) conditions

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I left some stuff out for simplicity - the main issue I was trying to figure out was when excelp would return something - and it seems that as long as excelp is able to execute the file it will not return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `execlp` function successfully starts the given program, it does **not** return.  The current program image gets replaced with the program image of the new program.  So even if the new program exits with status -1, it still doesn't go back to the program that called `execlp`.

If you want to get the exit status of the child process, pass the address of an `int` to `wait` and read that:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if(argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error:: Expecting an Argument!\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
  pid_t pid;
  pid = fork();
  if (pid == -1 {
      perror("fork failed");
      exit(-1);
  } else if (pid == 0) {
    execlp("./testing","testing",NULL);
    perror("execlp failed");
    exit(-1);
  }
  int status;
  wait(&status);
  printf("child exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
  printf("Parent and child done\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output:

```
Error:: Expecting an Argument!
Parent and child done
```

is from

```
(first line) child process tries to run but no command line parameter.  
(second line) parent process finishes
```

Comment: yes I understand that - but I was thinking `fprintf(stderr, "I want to get to here...\n");` should've also run since the child process is returning -1

Comment: an important detail.  the `exec*()` functions do not return, unless the operation failed